# How can I have PHP send Chinese characters in an email?

Tags: php, html, email, utf-8, chinese-locale

I've already scoured StackOverflow trying to find the answer but none of the answers provided to similar questions have solved my problem.

So I have a pretty basic form here, and I want it to be able to accept Chinese characters, and then send the data in an email. (Note: Chinese characters appear on my webpage with **no** issue)

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<head>
<link href="tour.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<?php include('tour-form.php') ?>

<div class="form">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
                 <br>

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="tour.html">

                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="col-xs-2 control-label">姓名</label>
                        <div class="col-xs-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="您叫？" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>">
                            <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
                        </div>
                    </div>

           </form> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

php:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];

        $to = 'email@website.com'; 
        $subject = 'New Form';

        $body = "Customer: $name\n";

        // Check if name has been entered
        if (!$_POST['name']) {
            $errName = 'Please enter your name';
        }
    // If there are no errors, send the email
if (!$errName) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Form Submitted!</div>';
    } else {
        $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Error!</div>';
    }
}
    }
?>
```

My code works well enough to send the email, but if I put Chinese characters in the form field, in the email they come out as really weird symbols.

Please help!!

Comment: set `headers` with UTF

Comment: Can you explain more clearly how to do that?

Comment: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /srv/disk8/2021869/www/maitxhomes.com/tour.html:12) in /srv/disk8/2021869/www/maitxhomes.com/tour-form.php on line 3"

That's what appeared at the top of the page after I added this:

Comment: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: header like this `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
            $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";`

Comment: I tried just copying and pasting that into my php file and it did not work.

Comment: i have added example. not exact code

Comment: Try using utf-8 or utf-16 instead of `ISO-8859-1` from above comment and when you use utf-8 or 16 then also change this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">` respectively... And mentions at the top of you html page this `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=PUT-RESPECTIVE-ENCODING'); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use Chinese language inside the email body by using this:

```
$headers = 'From: youremail@example.com' . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8"; // add header
if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    // your stuff
} else {
    // your stuff
}
```